# Publishing Facebook Graph actions that reference more than one object

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to publish actions to the graph that have this sort feel:

```
John voted for Pauly Shore as "best actor of all time"
Rick voted for Gary Busey  as "best actor of all time"
Jane voted for Gary Busey  as "most attractive actor of all time"
```

In our app, "Pauly Shore" and "best actore of all time" are each objects themselves.

Can you add actions to the graph that reference more than object? What's the best way to add these actions to the graph?